# What is the difference between creating an object with parentheses and equals

Tags: c++, object, initialization

if I create a class object like this

```
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML Window");
```

it works fine, but if I create it like this

```
sf::RenderWindow window = sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML Window");
```

I get an error

> attempting to reference a deleted function.

Don't they mean the same thing? **Why does one work and the other does not?**

Comment: They mean the same thing in C++17. If you have an old compiler then you'll have to do it the first way

Comment: @M.M I use Visual Studio 2017

Comment: Thy mean the same, but it is inefficient to do it so. The problem might lie in the copy constructor of that object.

Comment: The error message implies that there is a copy-constructor present but has been marked [`=delete`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Deleted_functions) prohibiting it's use. But strangely enough inspecting the [github source for SFML RenderWindow](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/include/SFML/Graphics/RenderWindow.hpp) doesn't show this to be so. For what it's worth I think this is a good question.

Comment: @craig5075 Looking at the link you gave, `RenderWindow` derives from `RenderTarget`, which in turn derives from `NonCopyable`, which declares its copy constructor and `operator=` `private`.  Confusing error message tho.

Comment: @Artem try to find out whether it supports `/std:c++17`

Comment: @MM It's not that - see my comment above.

Comment: @PaulSanders Good catch. I think the point MM is making is that  C++17 does not have the same requirement that the copy constructor used during copy-initialization must still be callable (even if the copy-construction will be elided.)

Comment: @acraig5075 Oh, OK.  I was not familiar with that.